# Invalid region error when using google-cloud-python API to access Dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-python

I am trying to create a cluster in Dataproc using [google-cloud-python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/tree/master/dataproc) library, however, when setting `region = 'us-central1'` I get below exception:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Region 'us-central1' is invalid.
Please see https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/regional-endpoints
for additional information on regional endpoints
```

Code (based on [example](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/dataproc/gapic/v1/api.html#google.cloud.dataproc_v1.ClusterControllerClient.create_cluster)):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from google.cloud import dataproc_v1

client = dataproc_v1.ClusterControllerClient()

project_id = 'my-project'
region = 'us-central1'
cluster = {...}

response = client.create_cluster(project_id, region, cluster)
```

Answer (score 4):

Dataproc uses `region` field for routing REST requests, however, the field is not used in gRPC clients (hence the error).

Only the `global` multiregion can be accessed through the default endpoint. To use a regional endpoint such as `us-central1`, you have to configure the endpoint to address on the client's `transport`.

The Dataproc regional endpoints follow this pattern: `<region>-dataproc.googleapis.com:443`. The `region` field should be set to the same value as the region in the endpoint.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from google.cloud import dataproc_v1
from google.cloud.dataproc_v1.gapic.transports import cluster_controller_grpc_transport

transport = cluster_controller_grpc_transport.ClusterControllerGrpcTransport(
    address='us-central1-dataproc.googleapis.com:443')
client = dataproc_v1.ClusterControllerClient(transport)

project_id = 'my-project'
region = 'us-central1'
cluster = {...}

response = client.create_cluster(project_id, region, cluster)
```

Comment: [The related issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/5884#issuecomment-494879727) was raised in **google-cloud-python** repository, so probably they will make it easier to manage someday.

Answer (score 2):

As for now, the recommended way to change the default API endpoint is [to use `client_options`](https://googleapis.dev/python/dataproc/latest/gapic/v1/api.html#google.cloud.dataproc_v1.ClusterControllerClient):

> **client_options** (Union[dict, google.api_core.client_options.ClientOptions]) – Client options used to set user options on the client. **API Endpoint should be set through client_options.**

Here's an example with loading credentials from json file (Python 3.6+ syntax with f-string):

```py
from google.cloud.dataproc_v1 import ClusterControllerClient


client = ClusterControllerClient.from_service_account_file(
             service_account_json_path,
             client_options={'api_endpoint': f'{your_region}-dataproc.googleapis.com:443'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly using the [google-cloud-java](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-dataproc) client:

```
ClusterControllerSettings settings =
     ClusterControllerSettings.newBuilder()
        .setEndpoint("us-central1-dataproc.googleapis.com:443")
        .build();
 try (ClusterControllerClient clusterControllerClient = ClusterControllerClient.create(settings)) {
   String projectId = "my-project";
   String region = "us-central1";
   Cluster cluster = Cluster.newBuilder().build();
   Cluster response =
       clusterControllerClient.createClusterAsync(projectId, region, cluster).get();
 }
```