# How submit a job on Dataproc for us-east4 region using Python SDK

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-python

I want to submit a job on the Google Cloud Dataproc for us-east4 region. I have used the following code which gives me an error.

```py
job_clnt = dataproc_v1.JobControllerClient()
project_id = self.project_id
region = cluster_region
job_clnt.submit_job(project_id, region, job)
```

Error is:

> 400 Region 'us-east4' specified in request does not match endpoint region 'global'. To use 'us-east4' region, specify 'us-east4' region in request and configure client to use 'us-east4-dataproc.googleapis.com:443' endpoint.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid region error when using google-cloud-python API to access Dataproc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53401219/invalid-region-error-when-using-google-cloud-python-api-to-access-dataproc)

Comment: Can you paste your dataproc submit script ?

Comment: job_clnt = dataproc_v1.JobControllerClient()
        project_id = self.project_id
        region = cluster_region
        job_clnt.submit_job(project_id, region, job)

Answer (score 2):

tl/dr: you have to set endpoint address on the stub: `configure client to use 'us-east4-dataproc.googleapis.com:443' endpoint.`

This answer may be relevant:
[Invalid region error when using google-cloud-python API to access Dataproc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53401219/invalid-region-error-when-using-google-cloud-python-api-to-access-dataproc/53401232#53401232)

Comment: Yes, the above answer is relevant only for cluster-related activity but I want to submit a job for the particular region

Comment: The same thing applies to submitting jobs as well, you have to set endpoint URI on the stub and its done the same way.